# Error "std::bad_alloc" wicked pdf wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wickedpdf gem for generating pdf's in my rails application. Every thing runs normally, except for few requests on production fail, with the following error log.

> Error: Failed to execute:
>   ["/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--page-size", "A4", "--margin-top", "20", "--margin-bottom", "25", "--margin-left", "0", "--margin-right", "0", "--footer-spacing", "5", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20160714-2229-1bb7qcg.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20160714-2229-18kjik5.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20160714-2229-1t66b4y.pdf"]
>   Error: PDF could not be generated!
>    Command Error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

I am not able to reproduce this on my local/staging.

*The following is my setup:*
Production server running on Centos 7 on AWS-EC2. Copied wkhtmltopdf binary for linux 64-bit from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html to `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` with version 0.12.0. Added initializer for Wickedpdf to point to wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with wkhtmltopdf-0.12.2.1. Also PDFs were rendering very slow

wkhtmltopdf v0.12.0-0.12.2 uses high resolution (about 1200dpi) to print PDFs which caused slow rendering issue. In the version 0.12.3 the resolution was dropped to 72dpi which fixed the performance issue (See [this issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1510) for the details)

Upgrade to v0.12.4.0 fixed the `Command Error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with @Hirurg103 answer's I had an idea of workaround: I set the `dpi` attribute for my pdf and it worked

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "my-report, dpi: 75
    end
  end
```